# Automounts: All mounting and will not umount on its own

Tags: backup, automounting, sles, autofs

I have a few SLES 11.2 servers.  They do something really strange with automount.  We have nearly 500 possible automounts our users and their codes may need, including automount entries for each user's $HOME.  No problem.  If I visit any one of the thousands of Linux workstations or servers we support, I may see 10-20 automounts.  And they unmount as expected.

But, we think since going to SLES 11.2 and KDE4, though we could be wrong, we have a few systems, noticeably one of the head-nodes on an HPCE Linux cluster, that has ALL 500 automounts alive and mounted... And they do not unmount on their own???  But, we can run a script to manually umount them and all but the few that are really active, unmount without complaint?

I wonder if it is some glitch in the nightly tape backup program?   Maybe it wakes all the automounts but does not back them up?   But why do they stay up?

MORE INFO:

We use autofs to automount just about all data we access.  This includes users' $HOME, applications, input data for applications, results from applications, etc.

We use NIS maps to define the automount parameters and options for each mount.  This includes, the NFS hostname, the filesystem name on the NFS host, the mount point on the client of that automount.  Also, the 'exports' file on the NFS servers also play a part in who can mount and what options/restrictions there are.

The "/etc/auto.master" tells autofs/automountd which NIS map to look in for the hundreds of different mounts.

The user or program or app that needs the data in these automounts simply accesses the directory bu a "cd" or a "ls" or "cat", etc the mount is created.  As long as someone is in the mounted directory or a file is being read or written from it, it stays mounted.  If the mount is idle for 5 or 10 minutes, the automount is unmounted.

All this works as designed on tons of Linux and Unix clients.

Occasionally, we will see a client that does not appear to be using an automounted filesystem, yet it stays mounted past the timeout.  But this is weirder... This server is mounted EVERY defined and accessible mount in ALL of the NIS automount maps.  And, it is not unmounting them after 10 minutes?

We could understand if it was, say the backup program, traversing every possible subdirectory and therefore activating all the automounts.  But even then, the automounts should unmount after the backups finish.  That does not seem to be the case.

I trust the updates answers your comments, @soubunmei
Mark, I have not tried the SIGUSR1.  Perhaps I will try that next time.

Comment: sorry but your question don't look very organised . by automount do you mean _the_ automount aka. autofs ? maybe you can briefly describe expected behaviour , thus letting us have a clue of what should be right before we know what is wrong .

Comment: as far as i know , automount aka. autofs is some filesystem that is dynamicly mounted exactly when the path get accessed , and unmounted after a pre-configured timeout . what is your specific working scenario ?

Comment: Could be a bug in, or unexpected config for, automount. If you send the automount daemon on the problem systems a SIGUSR1 signal, does it do a "forced expire", that is, does it unmount all unused mounts?

Comment: Was my update from last week (See "MORE INFO") not sufficient to clarify the question?  If so, why is it still appear Closed for Clarification @soubunmei ?

Comment: maybe we can use some filesystem auditing facility to find out when and by who files get accessed . [fa-trace](http://www.piware.de/2012/02/fatrace-report-system-wide-file-access-events/) is a utility around the _fanotify_ kernel framework , thats logs the accessd file path , the time , and the process , and this utility can run against a filesystem mountpoint .

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen with GNOME updates around file monitoring bits (e.g. nautilus) - it may be the same for KDE. I would look for anything that monitors file state, filesystem usage, or the like, and turn it off.